# Que mas tengo que hacer ademas de la importacion del tutorial de FusionCharts para qfunsione en Angular 12 me da este error?

Tags: angular, charts

Estoy trantando de implementar **FusionCHarts** en *Angular 12.0.4* y al seguir el tutorial me da el siguiente error al momento de compilar la aplicación.

```
PS D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui> ng serve
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\utils.js:23
            return new imports_1.R3SymbolsImportRewriter(r3SymbolsFile.fileName);
                                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileName' of null
    at Object.getImportRewriter (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\utils.js:23:72)
    at DtsRenderer.renderDtsFile (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:77:72)
    at D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:69:158    
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DtsRenderer.renderProgram (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\rendering\dts_renderer.js:69:26)
    at Transformer.transform (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:93:52)
    at D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\create_compile_function.js:52:42
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:36:17)    at D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (D:\Libraries\GitHub\toc-copextel-onContainer\toc-admin-gui\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
```